# How to create a new column based on row value in previous row in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a column which encodes a 1 if the Adjusted Closing Price of a stock at row T went up compared to the Adjusted Closing Price at row T-1, and encode a 0 if it went down instead.

The dataframe looks like:

[image]

E.g., at row index 1298 for the new column should be 0

What's the best possible way to get this done (e.g., via np.where()?) Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `sort_values` on your date column to make sure they are in the right order to perform the comparison, and then you can use `np.where` with `shift()` to compare the previous value in Adj Close with the current one:

```
# Sort by date
df.sort_values(by='Date',ascending=True)

# Create a column comparing previous Adj Close with current Adj Close
import numpy as np
df['i'] = np.where(df['Adj Close'].shift(1) < df['Adj Close'],1,0)
```

---

```
df
            Date        Open        High  ...  Adj Close    Volume  i
index                                     ...                        
1297  2021-03-01  104.540001  133.990005  ...     120.40  49597300  0
1298  2021-03-02  116.930000  133.199900  ...     118.18  33640400  0
1299  2021-03-03  122.500000  127.700000  ...     124.18  19173700  1
```